# Convert numbers in substring to words in java

Tags: java, string

I'm novice to java. I want to convert numbers in substring to English words with certain position in a string.

For example, the string `ABC12345DEFG` and `substring(3,8)` should output the following.

```
ABConetwothreefourfiveDEF
```

I tried with the following code but it only returned `ABCfiveDEFG`. Could you help me solve this problem?

```
String str = "ABC12345DEFG";
String newStr = "";
String words = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
for (char c:str.toCharArray()){
    int i = (int)(c-'0');
    for (int j=0; j<words.length; j++){
        if (i==j){
            newStr = str.replace(str.substring(3,8), words[j];
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(newStr);
```

Comment: As a side topic, it's better to just rely on the ascii code and map to the words in a string array so you can finish in O(n) instead of O(n2).

Comment: So, based on your code, you are replacing `12345` with each element in the `words` array, when you want to replace a single digit with the appropriate word instead - so your logic is off to start with.  Maybe use a `StringBuilder` to store the results, take each character from the `str`, check to see if it's a number or not and append the result to the `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 1):

1) You shouldn't be replacing all of substring(3,8), since you really just want to replace one character at a time.

2) Your line is changing newStr each time it hits. The final time is for 5, which is why you only have "ABCfiveDEFG"

3) Looping through the array to find an index that is equal to i is...weird? If j==i, then just use i, making sure it is in range.

```
String str = "ABC12345DEFG";
String newStr = "";
String words = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
for (char c:str.toCharArray()){
    int i = (int)(c-'0');
    if (i >= 0 && i < words.length)
        newStr += words[i];
    else
        newStr += c;
}
System.out.println(newStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
public static String exchange( final String txt, final String... numbers ) {
    String result = txt;
    for ( int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i ) {
        result = result.replace( Integer.toString( i ), numbers[i] );
    }
    return result;
}
```

Called like this:

```
exchange( "ABC12345DEF", "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" )
```

Returns this:

> ABConetwothreefourfiveDEF

Answer (score 1):

Few things that you could improve on is:

1. Change

   ```
   String words = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
   ```

   to

   ```
   String[] words = new String[]{"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
   ```

It's an array of strings and this is one correct way to represent it.

2. In your loop, change

   ```
   if (i==j){
       newStr = str.replace(str.substring(3,8), words[j];
   }
   ```

   to

   ```
   if (i == j) {
       newStr = str.replace(Character.toString(c), words[j]); // replace the numeric character with equivalent string
       str = newStr; // update the base string
    }
   ```

You were instead trying to replace the entire substring of numeric characters with just one string form the array.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is wrong with your code

try an easier way

```
    String str = "ABC12345DEFG";
    String newStr = "";
    String[] words = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
    for (char c:str.toCharArray()){
        int i = (int)(c-'0');
        if (i >= 1 && i <= 5) // or (words.length - 1)
        {
            newStr += words[i];
        }
        else {
            newStr += c;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(newStr);
```

**output**

```
ABConetwothreefourfiveDEFG
```

Answer (score 0):

All other give him the code but not point out the error of his code. It's not good for him because he is learning new language. I point out inline commend as below:

```
String str = "ABC12345DEFG";
String newStr = "";
String words = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"}; // Im not recommend to declare this defination because this data as a library. So you should map them as: 1->one, 2->two,... IF you just define as array, if the index is wrong => the data will be wrong
for (char c:str.toCharArray()){
    int i = (int)(c-'0'); // Should not declare variable inside the loop
    for (int j=0; j<words.length; j++){ // There are 2 loop => O(n2) => bad performance
        if (i==j){
            newStr = str.replace(str.substring(3,8), words[j]; // Wrong replace here, that why the final result is wrong
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(newStr);
```

My code is not the best but I believe it has good performance and clearly defination.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String str = "ABC12345DEFG";
    Map<Integer, String> numberInWord = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String>(5) {{
    put(0,"zero"); put(1,"one"); put(2,"two"); put(3,"three"); put(4,"four"); put(5,"five");
    }};
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : numberInWord.entrySet()){
        str = str.replace(entry.getKey().toString(), entry.getValue());
    }
    System.out.println(str);
}
```